How to type a custom map constructor with PhpStan so that an instance indexed on BackedEnum values will retain the exact key type?
Sorry about the confusing title, I wasn't sure how to best summarize the problem.
I've got a custom map class that takes array-key type keys, and I'm trying to create an instance with stricter value-of<BackedEnum> type keys.
PhpStan correctly detects an array using the enum values as keys, but when creating an instance of my custom map, it only detects strings.
Is there a way of typing the map constructor so that the value-of<Code> key type is retained, without having to create a sub-class or explicitly specifying the type with a @var annotation?
Playground example:
https://phpstan.org/r/6d38999c-fbfc-4b26-a811-9822c3571e23
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @template K of array-key
 * @template V
 */
class Map
{
    /**
     * @var array<K, V>
     */
    private array $array;

    /**
     * @var array<K>
     */
    private array $keys;

    /**
     * @param array<K, V> $a
     */
    final public function __construct(array $a = [])
    {
        $this->array = $a;
        $this->keys = \array_keys($a);
    }

    /**
     * @return array<K, V>
     */
    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return $this->array;
    }

    /**
     * @return array<K>
     */
    public function getKeys(): array
    {
        return $this->keys;
    }

    // ...
}

enum Code: string
{
    case FOO = 'foo';
    case BAR = 'bar';
}


class Test
{

    /**
     * This works.
     *
     * @return array<value-of<Code>, string>
     */
    public static function testArray(): array
    {
        return [
            Code::FOO->value => 'foz',
            Code::BAR->value => 'baz',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * This fails as expectd.
     *
     * @return array<value-of<Code>, string>
     */
    public static function testFailingArray(): array
    {
        return [
            Code::FOO->value => 'foz',
            Code::BAR->value => 'baz',
            'wrong' => 'nogood',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * FIXME This fails because the type infered from the constructor call is `Map<string, string>`.
     *
     * @return Map<value-of<Code>, string>
     */
    public static function testMap(): Map
    {
        return new Map([
            Code::FOO->value => 'foz',
            Code::BAR->value => 'baz',
        ]);
    }
}

